# Convert date format (yyyy-mm-dd to seven digit Julian format

Tags: vb.net, date, julian-date

Am working on a small application that generate Google query’s. With the operator "daterange:" you can limit your result. Exampel (“searchstring” daterange:juliandate)

The daterange operator in Google needs a seven digit Julian format. 
I have found some example like this

```
    datediff("yyyy","01/01/1900",date) & format(date,"y")
```

Need help to found some code solution to convert normal date-format to seven digit Julian format (VB-code).

Comment: What is a seven digit Julian format? I had _never_ heard of it.

Answer (score 0):

Start with import at start of your file

```
Imports System.Globalization
```

To convert your date use code below.

```
Dim dt As DateTime
Dim jc As String
dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2012/12/15", "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
jc = dt.Year.ToString + dt.DayOfYear.ToString
```